# Read the source code of .jar files with python

Tags: java, python, jar, extract, words

I want to read the source code of jar files and extract the words' frequency. I know that it is possible to read the content of jar files with Java editors, but I want to do this automatically with a python script.

Comment: A jar file is just a zip file.  Unzip it, and then read the relevant files.

Comment: Does it need to be Python? Can't you use Jython? In Jython you can do something like: java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream('path to the file inside the jar')

Comment: To be clear, a jar file contains compiled code, not source code.

Comment: @BrianPipa  A Jar file can contain the source (or any files), although not commonly.

Comment: @SteveSmith a jar file can contain ANY files, I know. I wasn't sure if he knew that jar files typically contain compiled code (class files). true, he could have a jar full of source - he didn't specify. This really shouldn't be tagged with java  the files are java but in this case they could be any text files. He's trying to solve this with Pythion, not java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you require a Python library specifically? [Krakatau](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau) is a command line tool in Python for decompiling `.jar` files, you can perhaps import it and use the relevant functions from inside your script.

Alternatively, you can call it, or any other command line `.jar` decompiler such as [Procyon](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/wiki/browse/),
 using Python's [Subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

In the 2nd case, you would most likely like to redirect and capture stdout and/or stderr. A basic call may look something like:

```
import os    
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
.
.
jar_decompiler_output = Popen(('jar_decompiler', '1stparam', '2ndparam',..), stdout= PIPE).communicate()[0].split(os.linesep)
```

Note that communicate() [returns a tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate).